# Spherical right triangles identities

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

We have a spherical triangles with angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ that have opposite sides of length $a,b,c$. So our triangle is right angled as we have that $\gamma = \frac{\pi}{2}$. I have to prove the following identities:

$\sin(\alpha) = \dfrac{\sin(a)}{\sin (c)}$,  $\,\cos(\alpha)=\dfrac{\cos(a)\sin(b)}{\sin(c)}\,$ and $\,\tan(\alpha) = \dfrac{\tan(a)}{\sin(b)}$.

I know this has something to do with the right spherical triangles identities but I'm struggling on how I should even start it. I think I could prove it fully myself if I just knew where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have the ten Napier’s rules for spherical right triangles. Any formula for right triangles should follow easily from these.

Comment: @Lubin So using those rules I've managed to prove the first two but I'm still stuck on the last one: $tan(\alpha)=\frac{tan(a)}{sin(b)}$, not really sure what to do with that

Comment: By definition, $\tan \theta = \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$. So if you've already gotten the previous two, the third should be easy.

Comment: Yet another approach for your last identity is to recognize it as rule $(R4)$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Napier's_rules_for_right_spherical_triangles

Comment: @Limitdoesnotexist: Can you cite the text book reference of this  problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first is taken from the Law of Sines:

$$ \dfrac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin (\gamma= \pi/2)} = \dfrac{\sin(a)}{\sin (c)}  $$

But better to start where you feel comfortably close to elementary trigonometry so you can relate.

By Law of Cosines where $(a,b,c) $ are side of a unit sphere:

$$\cos c=\cos a\cos b+ \sin a \sin b~ \cos \gamma $$
If $\gamma= \pi/2 $

$$\cos c=\cos a\cos b $$
You can consider a very small (so is a flat ) right triangle to get back Pythagoras thm by power series expansion for cos function.

$$ 1-c^2/2!+..\approx 1-a^2/2!+..* 1-b^2/2!+..$$
$$ \to ~ c^2 = a^2+b^2, \text{ where c is the hypotenuse in Euclidean geometry. }$$

Then add on other things